# How to paginate the results from a Custom Finder in CakePHP 3

Tags: pagination, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

How do you paginate the results from a Custom Finder in CakePHP 3 (specifically 3.7)?

I have a Model with a custom finder in it:

```
// src/Model/Table/RevisionFiltersTable.php
public function findRegulatoryNotifications($date_start, $date_end, $regulation_id = 1, $u_id, $o_id, $count_only = false)
{

}
```

Inside this finder there are methods to use the ORM and execute a query, returning `$query->toArray()`

At the moment I am calling this manually in a Controller method as follows:

```
$RevisionFilters = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('RevisionFilters');
$data = $RevisionFilters->findRegulatoryNotifications(...);
```

It returns all the correct data but isn't paginated. For example if there are 55 rows I get an array with 55 keys.

The parameters I'm passing in are appropriate for the signature of `findRegulatoryNotifications()`

I've read about using Pagination and Custom Finders in the docs https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate

But I can't see how to do this in my Controller.

The docs give this as an example:

```
$this->paginate = [
        'finder' => [
            'tagged' => $customFinderOptions
        ]
    ];
```

So I assumed I could do something like:

```
$RevisionFilters->paginate = [
        'finder' => [
            'regulatoryNotifications' => $customFinderOptions
        ]
    ];
```

I don't understand what `$customFinderOptions` should be set to in this case.

Assuming I could get past this how would I then pass in my arguments to `findRegulatoryNotifications()`?

Can't provide more code than this as I've no idea how to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what a finder method is supposed to look like, finders accept only two arguments, the first being the query itself, and the second being an array of options (which are passed to the second argument of `Query::find()`), and that's what `$customFinderOptions` would be in that example, an array of options.

What you have there is just a table method, if you wanted to use that for pagination, the method would need to return a query object, you'd invoke the method manually and pass its return value to the paginator.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**
- **[Cookbook > Pagination > Using Controller::paginate()](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate)**